# Firebase - iOS App stuck on launch screen when first installed

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, debugging, google-cloud-firestore

**I've been working on an app that uses Firebase Cloud Firestore and recently discovered that when that app is deleted and reinstalled, it gets stuck on the launchscreen. However, when it is stuck, if the user turns off their phone or goes to the homescreen it asks for the app's required permissions and works. It also works when the app is quit after running.**

Side note:
The problem began soon after I added firebase through cocoapods. Also the same firebase instance used to be connected to a different xcode project.

Console output when the app is first installed:

```
**2020-06-08 16:06:19.880252-0400 [9419:1214490]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036001] Analytics screen reporting is disabled. UIViewController transitions will not be logged.
2020-06-08 16:06:20.429337-0400 [9419:1214491] [GoogleDataTransport][I-GDTCOR001006] (/Users/Programmer/Programming/XCode Projects/ v2/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCOREvent.m:59) : There was an error saving the new counter value to disk.
2020-06-08 16:06:20.430417-0400 [9419:1214491] [GoogleDataTransport][I-GDTCOR001006] (/Users/Programmer/Programming/XCode Projects/ v2/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCOREvent.m:59) : There was an error saving the new counter value to disk.
2020-06-08 16:06:20.607935-0400 [9419:1214490] 6.23.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60402000 started
2020-06-08 16:06:20.612005-0400 [9419:1214490] 6.23.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http://google.com/RfcP7r)
2020-06-08 16:06:22.135768-0400 [9419:1214499] 6.23.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-06-08 16:06:41.606778-0400 [9419:1214491] [] tcp_output [C1.1:3] flags=[R.] seq=648018085, ack=515684647, win=1024 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=515684647, snd_una=648018085
2020-06-08 16:06:41.608988-0400 [9419:1214491] Connection 1: received failure notification
2020-06-08 16:06:41.609528-0400 [9419:1214491] Connection 1: failed to connect 3:-9816, reason -1
2020-06-08 16:06:41.610032-0400 [9419:1214491] Connection 1: encountered error(3:-9816)
2020-06-08 16:06:51.654539-0400 [9419:1214491] [] tcp_output [C2.1:3] flags=[R.] seq=3609595602, ack=3267009203, win=1024 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=3267009203, snd_una=3609595602
2020-06-08 16:06:51.658329-0400 [9419:1214491] Connection 2: received failure notification
2020-06-08 16:06:51.658948-0400 [9419:1214491] Connection 2: failed to connect 3:-9816, reason -1
2020-06-08 16:06:51.659298-0400 [9419:1214491] Connection 2: encountered error(3:-9816)
2020-06-08 16:06:51.702737-0400 [9419:1214491] [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_handle_fatal_alert(1873) [C3.1:2][0x10960cad0] read alert, level: fatal, description: inappropriate fallback
2020-06-08 16:06:51.704257-0400 [9419:1214491] [BoringSSL] boringssl_session_handshake_incomplete(164) [C3.1:2][0x10960cad0] SSL library error
2020-06-08 16:06:51.704448-0400 [9419:1214491] [BoringSSL] boringssl_session_handshake_error_print(111) [C3.1:2][0x10960cad0] 4452304296:error:1000043e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK:/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/boringssl-283.120.1/ssl/tls_record.cc:587:SSL alert number 86
2020-06-08 16:06:51.704590-0400 [9419:1214491] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_handshake_negotiate_proceed(726) [C3.1:2][0x10960cad0] handshake failed at state 12288
2020-06-08 16:06:51.707766-0400 [9419:1214491] Connection 3: received failure notification
2020-06-08 16:06:51.708307-0400 [9419:1214491] Connection 3: failed to connect 3:-9858, reason -1
2020-06-08 16:06:51.708442-0400 [9419:1214491] Connection 3: encountered error(3:-9858)
2020-06-08 16:06:51.713002-0400 [9419:1214491] Task <B08F2EB1-6A8D-4BB9-B57B-995FC2E99A0F>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1200 [3:-9858])**
```

———————

Console output when the app is working and already installed:

```
**2020-06-08 16:07:23.627230-0400 [9428:1215582]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036001] Analytics screen reporting is disabled. UIViewController transitions will not be logged.
2020-06-08 16:07:24.215799-0400 [9428:1215603] 6.23.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60402000 started
2020-06-08 16:07:24.216140-0400 [9428:1215603] 6.23.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http://google.com/RfcP7r)
2020-06-08 16:07:24.703524-0400 [9428:1215582] 6.23.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-06-08 16:07:24.754678-0400 [9428:1215599] 6.23.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
2020-06-08 16:07:25.552146-0400 [9428:1215604] 6.23.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023130] Configuration not found. Using default configuration**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I could just add another fake view because the problem was that the view being displayed was causing problems.